# How can I pass values with spaces in them to the Execute Windows Batch command build step in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, hudson

**My Setup:** Mercurial DCVS (latest) and Jenkins CI (1.509.2) on an Amazon EC2 Windows 2008 R2 instance.

I have a Jenkins build job that needs to create a VPN link between the build server and our production server so that I can deploy the build artifacts via FTP.

I’m attempting to use the Execute Windows Batch command build step to execute a command similar to this:

`rasdial NameOfConnection user@host.domain "password with spaces in it"`

If I execute the command on the server in the console (i.e. RDC to the EC2 VM and execute the command in a console) it works perfectly, no problems at all. Executing in using the Execute Windows Batch command build step fails completely. No amount of changing the quote type i.e. double to single, or mixing and matching the pairs e.g. '"blah blah blah"' has any effect.

*... time passes ...*

I’ve just tried moving the commands into a separate batch file ("ConnectNameOfConnectionVPN.bat") to be called from the Execute Windows Batch command build step i.e. move, what appears to be an issue with quotation marks outside of Jenkins. Unfortunately, this too seems to have no impact, in fact I get the following error, which suggests that possibly something else is going on.

`Remote Access error 623 - The system could not find the phone book entry for this connection.`

At this point I don’t know. I’ve seen the same error when executing the commands directly in the console.

Any help/hints graciously accepted.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually if this happens I consider following factors while troubleshooting:

1. Environment variables, running directly from console and via Jenkins might be different
2. If you are running the batch on VM via Jenkins, the remote session may be a factor
3. Working directory

Comment: Re 1; Possibly, but I’m not using any environment variables in the connection. 2; Maybe. 3; I don’t believe this is likely. Thanks.